# recomendation of reverse-proxy to count hits to all endpoints in a service

Tags: monitoring, http, proxy, go

I have a use case where I need to count every request arriving to all endpoints of my services on Kubernetes. For example

```
**endpoint**                      **counter**
addr:port/a:                     1
addr:port/a/pathX:               4
addr:port/a/pathY:               5
addr:port/a/pathY/subpathM:      7
addr:port/b:                     3
addr:port/b/another-path:        7
```

Currently, I'm using a custom reverse-proxy that I've implemented in Go, but it has a terrible performance. My server can handle roughly handle ~16k RPS, with Envoy ~15.8k, with Traefik ~12k, and with my implementation ~2k :(

Envoy (or even Traefik) has much better performance than my proxy but AFAIK they can't count hits to endpoints as I need. This counters should be exposed as metrics to be scraped by Prometheus.

Have Envoy or Traefik this feature that I need? If yes, how can I use it? If they don't, there is another proxy with this feature? Perhaps Nginx or HAproxy.

In case of doesn't exists a proxy with this feature, which GoLang HTTP library has best performance to implement this kind of proxy?

My deployment is made on Kubernetes and the proxy is supposed to be a sidecar of each pod of my system. Performance is a must and it is better if it have a small memory footprint.

Any idea is welcome :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, as no one came with a suggestion I will post myself a solution for my question ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

I leverage [FastHTTP](https://github.com/valyala/fasthttp), a low latency HTTP library in GoLang, to implement my own reverse proxy. In my experiments, I got a performance close to Envoy that is good enough for my use case. However, FastHTTP isn't enabled for HTTP/2.0, thus in a near future I'll have to update my architecture with another custom reverse proxy.

[image: performance comparation of different reverse-proxies]

I used this [comment](https://github.com/valyala/fasthttp/issues/64#issuecomment-261882691) to scaffold my reverse-proxy implementation. It was quite simple to put everything working.